# Draw Border around UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I am needing a border around a UIImage.  The UIImage is added to a PDF file.  Here is the code for drawing the image currently.

```
- (void) drawImage2
{
    UIImage * demoImage = self.imageCopy;
    NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(demoImage, 0.80);
    CGDataProviderRef dp = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(( CFDataRef)jpegData);
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dp, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage] drawInRect:CGRectMake(513, 314, 135, 135)];  
}
```

Any suggestions for how I can do this?  I know how to do it using CALayers with a UIImageView, but not sure here since I don't have the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithBorderFromImage:(UIImage*)source;
{
  CGSize size = [source size];
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
  [source drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0); 
  CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect);
  UIImage *testImg =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return testImg;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP wants to draw a border around a UIImage, not a UIImageView.

Comment: @0x7fffffff : He would be adding the image to some imageview after setting the image. so, I meant, When he wants to display that image on imageview, my answer would be useful.

Comment: You should consider reading the entire question and not just the title. The image will be added to a PDF and not to an image view, and the code you've provided is for something the OP specifically said he already knows how to do.